# Is it possible to use context in a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, static

I created this map in flutter: `final Map<int, Widget> buildImage`.

For one of the widgets within the map, I use a `showCupertinoModalPopup()`, however, it requires context. When I initialize it like this:

`showCupertinoModalPopup(
  context: context,
 );`

I get the following error: `Only static members can be accessed in initializers`.

I was wondering if there was any way to solve this.

EDIT: Here is the code to further clarify the problem.

```
class NewReminderScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewReminderScreenState createState() => _NewReminderScreenState();
 }

class _NewReminderScreenState extends State<NewReminderScreen> {
  static String title;
  static String description;
  static DateTime _dateTime;

  int sharedValue = 0;

  final Map<int, Widget> dateTimePlace = const <int, Widget>{
    0: Text('Time'),
    1: Text('Place'),
  };

  final Map<int, Widget> buildPage = <int, Widget>{
    0: Container(
        RaisedButton(
         onPressed: (){
          showCupertinoModalPopup(
           context: context, <-This is the error
          );
         },
        ),
       ),
     1: Container(),
```

When I do this, i get an error saying that only static members can be accessed in initializers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showCupertinoModalPopup(...)` is a method, you can directly call it whenever you need. There is no need to define it before using.

And if you are using `StatelessWidget`, you can convert it to `StatefulWidget` and you can then use `context` anywhere in the class.

If you still want to stick to `StatelessWidget`, you can pass the `context` from the `build()` method.

---

Update:

I think using a variable isn't a good idea, you can change your `buildPage` variable to a method like this:

```
Widget buildPage(int index) {
  switch(index) {
    case 0:
      return Container(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // no error in using context
            showCupertinoModalPopup(context: context);
          },
        ),
      );
      break;

    case 1: 
      return Container();
  }
  return Container();
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with partial code, maybe it will clarify what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, this is a good alternative to what I am doing and solves my problem. Thank you for the help.